# Releasing only changed components

Tags: java, maven, release

we have Java project where we should deliver only artifacts that were changed but in the same time have product that contains latest released version of not changed components and changed components in this release.
We do the builds using Maven 3.

Let's see if we have product 1.1-SNAPSHOT (means it's under development) where 6 components have their own release versions.

Now if would have structure like:

```
- c1 - 1.0-SNAPSHOT
  |- m1 - 2.0-SNAPSHOT
  |- m2 - 3.0-SNAPSHOT
- c2 - 4.0-SNAPSHOT
  |- m3 - 5.0-SNAPSHOT
  |- m4 - 6.0-SNAPSHOT
```

where c is parent component and m is module. Versions are taken randomly. There could be some dependencies, like m4 depends on m2.

Let's think we have updated m2 module and we want to release it. How we can do it? Manually only start release process on the m2 and m4 modules? What to tag question also arises? I suppose it should be the whole product containing new revision used for tagging for just released modules and revision of the sources for not updated modules.

Next what we want is to create product release package which will be 1.1 version and which will include latest released version for m1 (it can be 0.99) and m3 (it can be 4.99) which can be take from release of 1.0 of the product since they were not changed. Also new just released versions for m2 (it will be 3.0) and m4 ( it will be 6.0) should be part of 1.1 package. How it can be done?

The only solution I see is to use maven-version-plugin but it requires several hack development in the process.

The idea is to have minimum builds and have just released modules that were changed.

What maven can offer to have this automatically? Maven-release-plugin is not helpful at this level. How to do the release of just changed components? I started thinking perhaps we don't need to use SNAPSHOT in order to support this ideology.

Thank you.

Comment: @Andrew, the app can be any set of any jars. We don't have it but how the purpose of the jar file can affect the whole release process?

Comment: If it has a GUI it can be deployed using JWS.  JWS apps. support extensions.  Extensions can encapsulate groups of Jars and ensure the end user of those Jars is kept up to date.  So you can have 'dev' & 'production' extensions ( as well as versions of each), with easy management of the resources between versions.  But I thought I'd check before going into detail.

Comment: @AndrewThompson, thank you. It can be useful but for deployment phase and release pipeline, but the issue is in Release phase and how to do release of just updated components, including tagging and updating the versions.